# 1D Heat Equation with Insulated Boundary Conditions; Green's Function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, fourier-transform, greens-function

I would like to determine the solution to the 1D heat equation where the initial condition is a Delta function at the boundary

- $$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = D \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$$
- $$x \in [0, L], t \in [0, \infty]$$
- $$u(0,x) = \beta \delta(x)$$
- $$ u_{x} (0,t) = u_{x}(L,t) =0$$

Physically, a finite amount of mass $\beta$ is concentrated at one end of an insulated bar of length $L$ at time $t=0$ and I want to know the evolution of this mass distribution throughout time. The total amount of mass in the bar should always remain $\beta,$ and the steady solution should be $u(x,\infty) = \frac{\beta}{L}.$

Is this initial condition equivalent to just solving find the Green's function? If so, how do I proceed?

Comment: The equation being linear you can set $\beta = 1$. Also your boundary conditions are not of type Neumann homogeneous: how can you know the mass is constant?

Comment: @blamethelag True, good point. I know the mass is constant because the boundaries are insulated so no mass should be able to escape. Your comment made me realize I had a typo in my boundary conditions.

Comment: If you know spectral theory this boils down to find the eigenvectors of the Neumann Laplacian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental solution (Green's function) in an unbounded domain is
$$
u_0(x,t) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi Dt}} \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{4Dt}\right).
$$

Note that this satisfies the BC at $x=0$ but not at $x=L$.  To build that in use method of images:
$$
u(x,t) = \beta\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty u_0(x+2nL, t) = \frac{\beta}{2\sqrt{\pi D t}}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty  \exp\left(-\frac{(x+2nL)^2}{4Dt}\right).
$$
That is, imagine an initial condition with a delta function at $x=0, x=\pm 2L, x=\pm 4L, \ldots$. By symmetry the BC at $x=L$ will now also be satisfied.

Note that the average mass from $0$ to $L$ will not be $\beta/L$, but rather $\beta/(2L)$.  Roughly speaking only the right 'half' of the delta function is in the domain (if you like imagine the initial condition being a very tall Gaussian peak centred at zero.  Only half of that peak is in the domain).

Comment: What about putting the Delta function at $\epsilon?$ The total mass should be $\beta/L$, and then you can let $\epsilon \to 0.$ Do you have a reference for the unbounded solution as well?

Comment: If the initial mass is at $\epsilon > 0$, then yes, the average mass will be $\beta/L$.  But there's no reason the $\epsilon \to 0$ limit should be the same as the $\epsilon=0$ case.  I mean, if you took the $\epsilon \to 0$ limit from below, the mass would be zero.

Comment: And any book on introductory PDEs will have the fundamental solution of the heat equation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please see my new question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4723649/1d-heat-equation-with-insulated-boundaries-with-dirac-delta if you are interested.